# Comparing txt file data with input String in Android

Tags: java, android, file-io

am just working with some dictionaries app thing so there is a text file that I can get all words with there definition so I face this problem.

this is the main activity with it xml file which contains only text view.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView mtextview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mtextview=findViewById(R.id.tv);
    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getAssets().open("cool.txt")));
        while (true){
            String readline =bufferedReader.readLine();
            if (readline!=null){

                StringTokenizer stringTokenizer=new StringTokenizer(readline,",");
                String nexttoken=stringTokenizer.nextToken();
                String nexttoken2=stringTokenizer.nextToken();

                       if (nexttoken =="black"){
                           mtextview.setText(nexttoken2);
                       }else{
                           mtextview.setText("empty");
                       }

            }else {
                return;
            }

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

there this a assets file folder which contains cool.txt file and that file also contain this 3 lines.

```
color,name
black,white
00000,11111
```

so every time I run this code it print "empty".

But I want the result that is :-   white

please help I don't know what is wrong with this code.

Comment: Put the breakpoints and debug the code

Comment: breakpoints where sir?

Comment: In the code at certain places for debugging.

Comment: I do but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

You loop over every line in the file, but don't break out of it once your token has been found.

What happens in the loop is you first have `nexttoken` equal 'color', then 'black', then '00000'.  This means your if function sets the text in mtextview to 'empty', then to 'white', then to 'empty'.

Comment: could you explain more I did't get you sir

Comment: The issue lies in that the code is correct but the logic is incorrect.  For each step of the loop, print the parameters out, and you will see clearly what is happening in the code.  You can't debug blindly.

Comment: I try many times like for an hour and I still got nothing.can you please show me using the code. please?